# How to add EBCDIC support on debian/ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, character-encoding

I have to add EBCSIC text support to deal with IBM OS text messages. I have succesfuly added EBCDIC support to a CentOS box by adding lang and encoding to `/etc/i18n/sysconfig`.

I searched in the docs and the equivalent should be in debian `/etc/default/locale` but it didn't work.
I have checked and the EBCDIC support is present under `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps/`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert *files* which are encoded in EBCDIC to ASCII and vice versa (using [**`iconv`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html) or [**`dd`**](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html)), but making a *locale* which uses EBCDIC would require more than making a few table-entry changes.

That is because the locale tables only identify which character codes are printable, which are controls, etc.  EBCDIC uses a different *order* of the codes, so that digits in EBCDIC are different codes in ASCII, alphabetic characters are in different places, etc.  Making existing programs which use ASCII communicate with a system that reads/writes EBCDIC would require a two-way transformation between the two encodings.

In principle, a program such as [**`luit`**](http://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html) could be *extended* to do this mapping.  (It doesn't do this now).  Even if appropriate tables were added, then there is the additional problem that only simple command-line programs would work: you couldn't run `vi`.

Further reading:

- [Difference Between EBCDIC and ASCII](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/communication-technology/difference-between-ebcdic-and-ascii/)
- [ASCII and EBCDIC Compared](http://www.dynamoo.com/technical/ascii-ebcdic.htm)
- [ASCII to EBCDIC conversion](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/unix/bpxa1p03.html)
- [Lost in Translation 3 - Converting Between Code Pages](http://www.longpelaexpertise.com/ezine/LostinTranslation3.php)