# How to print an EBCDIC character table to stdout

Tags: command-line, ebcdic

So `ascii` will print an ascii character table to stdout. Is there a way to print the same thing, but for the EBCDIC character encoding?

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102040/how-to-add-ebcdic-support-on-debian-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

There is no unified base EBCDIC table like there is for ASCII.

That's probably your main issue here. ASCII actually is 7 bit. Adding the 8 bit introduces the whacky world of incompatible regional tables. For EBCDIC there is no such safe zone. They are just "randomly" incompatible.

Pick 1:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/epfz/5.3?topic=documents-supported-ebcdic-code-pages

Comment: Ah god it's an even dumber format than I realised. OK, but what if I picked one? Is there a straightforward way to print it to stdout? Or is the best option to just make a plaintext file for the table and alias cat file?

Comment: I call it "historic data structure Tetris". Doesn't exist to my knowledge. Well, not for Linux in official capacity at least. On machines actually historically using EBCDIC there are typically digital manuals that have entries like the output of ascii. You could write it yourself by just looping over all bytes and outputting them in the chosen encoding. I mean now you know what encoding to choose. And why "EBCDIC" is not a valid choice. Or short: There is a reason I pointed to an IBM manual. I don't know where else to search for EBCDIC stuff. Sorry.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll leave this open for now, but I'll be accepting this answer unless something better comes along.

Comment: [Wikipedia page on EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) has a table of the "invariant subset" of EBCDIC = characters that *should* have the same assignments on all EBCDIC code pages that use the Latin alphabet. Note that the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/E/EBCDIC.html) suggests IBM may have tried to keep the official encoding tables secret; you'll also note that the Jargon File's description of EBCDIC is more than a little salty, apparently with good reason.

Comment: In my surprise I checked that page and found out why you wrote "should". Nice this even better then I thought: "In the following table, conformance to the invariant set is marked with green; collision with the invariant set is marked with red. " - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language_in_EBCDIC  Truly the gift that keeps on giving.

Answer (score 2):

Certain codepages like `cp37` can be converted to `ASCII`.
A script below prints out a table of code points and corresponding Unicode characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(unicode_strings);
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));

use strict;
use warnings;

use charnames qw(:short latin);
use Encode qw(from_to);

sub ebcdic_to_ascii {
    my $ebcdic_ord = shift;
    my $binary     = pack( 'C', $ebcdic_ord );
    from_to( $binary, 'cp37', 'latin1' );
    my $latin_ord = unpack( 'C', $binary );
    return $latin_ord;
}

sub describe_chr {
    my $x = ebcdic_to_ascii(shift);
    my $s = sprintf( "%c", utf8::unicode_to_native($x) );
    return $s =~ /[[:graph:]]/ ? $s : charnames::viacode($x);
}

for ( 0x0 .. 0xFF ) {
    printf "%02X %s\n", $_, describe_chr($_);
}
```

```
$ ./ebcdic | column
```